# Resetting basic authentication credentials with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, authentication, rest, reset, afnetworking

I am writing a REST client (with AFNetworking) and need the ability to trigger the creation of a new session within a single instance of an application. 
In other words, I would like to:
1 - Authenticate with server 
2 - Do some REST calls 
3 - Simulate "Log out"
4 - Re-authenticate with server 
5 - Do some more REST calls 
AFNetworking is great with making that initial authentication and REST calls, but I can't figure out how I would clear the session and "reset" the connection within the same instance.
When I used ASIHTTP, I just did:
[ASIHTTPRequest clearSession];
Is there a way to do something similar with AFNetworking?

Answer (score 9):

Use `AFHTTPClient` (see the API client in the example project).

Credentials can be set with `-setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:password:`. Each request created from that HTTP client will have an `Authorization` HTTP header, kind of like a browser session.

When the user logs out, or you want to clear credentials, do `-clearAuthorizationHeader`.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler.

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Rest calls as far as I know are not session based. Meaning you can't simulate an authentication and log-out session in a particular call. What I think you can do is to Authenticate for every call made to the end point. So for every end point(Method), you authenticate the caller. I think that's the bets you can do in a restful system.

Comment: hmm I played around with it a bit more and it looks like flushing the cookie cache seems to be doing the trick for me.: NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *cookies = [cookieStorage cookies];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
        NSLog(@"deleted cookie");
    }