# AFNetworking 2, log out, clear session

Tags: ios, objective-c, session, afnetworking, logout

I'm using `AFNetworking 2` and `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` credentials for digest authentication. Everything works fine. Now I want to log out and log in with another user, But I can't clear session. I tried everything. Clear caches, delete saved credentials, even set `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` manager.shouldusecredential Storage to. Nothing works. If I logout then wait for some time session clears automatically and I logged in with user successfully, but when I logout and login immediately credentials are wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting basic authentication credentials with AFNetworking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038801/resetting-basic-authentication-credentials-with-afnetworking)

Comment: This all work good for AFNetworking 1 not 2 :(

Comment: Here is the same question as mine, but solution is "This issue can be fixed easily by adding a random number to the end of the URL:". I can't add random number to my requested url, I need to request the same url, otherwise I can't be authorized.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568853/afnetworking-with-nsurlcredential)